# Getters and setters with magic PHP calls Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, magic-function

I'm not really experienced with PHP magic methods, and I'm trying to create implicit getters and setters that interact with Laravel framework. Now, I know there are accessors and mutators , but they have to be explicitly declared. What I would like is to make is some kind of implicit function instead of declaring them.
I saw this done in Zend framework, it was something like

```
public function __call ($method, $params) {

    $property = strtolower($this->_getCamelCaseToUnderscoreFilter()->filter(substr($method, 3)));

    if (!property_exists($this, $property))
        return null;
    // Getters
    elseif (substr($method, 0, 3) == 'get')
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }
    // Setters
    elseif (substr($method, 0, 3) == 'set')
    {
        $this->$property = $params[0];
        return $this;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

Now if I have a model with this function, I'll be able to do just `$model->getProperty()` or `$model->setProperty($property)`.
But I'm not sure how can I apply it to Laravel. any idea?

Comment: What properties of the model do you need this for? The properties of a model will generally comprise the columns of the table that the model reflects. What additional properties do you need?

Comment: Only the columns of the table. ]

Comment: Which brings me to my original question: What properties of the model do you need this for?

Comment: I'd like to create some abstract class and have all my models extend that class and thus, implement this function and have all models be able to access all their properties 
For now, I only need, id, email, first_name and last_name

Comment: Surely id is already defined (by default it's used for every model), and the other properties you list are surely only appropriate to certain models where they're columns in the table that the model reflects

Comment: of course. So I would do
class MyAbstractModel{ __call(){//like in example in the question}}
MyModel extends MyAbstractModel{//properties here}
So if I had $MyModelInstance->getProperty() the function should do return $MyModelInstance->property;

Comment: I would hope that your abstract model extends Eloquent, so you can use the magic getter/setter methods that are already defined in the Eloquent Model

Comment: Yes, it would extend Eloquent. The only difference is that I would like my methods to be implicit rather than explicit, so I can call $model->getProperty without actually defining the method

Comment: why not using eloquent own method? 

e.g: `setAttribute($property, $value)` for setter and `getAttribute($key)` for getter.

or directly access it from property setters and getters.

Answer (score 0):

I created a parent class for all of my Models named "Moam" (as *Mother of all Models*)
In this Moam I've implement those magic methods well known by good old Zend framework.

/app/Models/Moam.php is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/* Mother of all models*/
class Moam extends Model
{   
    /* Implementation of magical get and set method for manipulation model properties
     * i.e. setFirstName('xxx') sets property first_name to 'xxx'
     *      getFirstName() returns value of property first_name
     *
     * So Capitals replaced underscores (_) in property name
     */

    public function __call($methodName, $args) {
        if (preg_match('~^(set|get)([A-Z])(.*)$~', $methodName, $matches)) {

            $split = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$methodName);
            $property = strtolower (implode("_",array_slice($split,1)));

            $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
            if (!array_key_exists($property,$attributes)){
                Log::error(get_class($this) . ' has no attribute named "' . $property . '"');
                throw new Exception(get_class($this) . ' has no attribute named "' . $property . '"');
            } else {

                switch($matches[1]) {
                case 'set':
                    return $this->setAttribute($property, $args[0]);
                case 'get':
                    return ($attributes[$property]);
                }
            }
        }

        return parent::__call($methodName, $args);
    }
}
```

In other models you have to declare your models like this:

```
use App\Models\Moam;
...

class yourModelextends Moam{
   ...
}
```

Finally you can call setters and getters in form below:

```
$modelVariable->getAPropertyName();
$modelVariable->setAPropertyName(propertyValue);
```

For instance:

```
$desc = $event->getDescription();
$event->setDescription("This is a blah blah blah...");
```